# Saving Spark DataFrames with nested User Data Types

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to save (as a parquet file) a Spark DataFrame that contains a custom class as a column. This class is composed by a Seq of another custom class. To do so, I create an UserDefinedType class for each of these classes, in a similar way to VectorUDT. I can work with the dataframe as I intended but cannot save it to disk as a parquet (or jason) 
I reported it as a bug, but maybe there is a problem with my code. I've implemented a simpler example to show the problem:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[AUDT])
case class A(list:Seq[B])

class AUDT extends UserDefinedType[A] {
  override def sqlType: DataType = StructType(Seq(StructField("list", ArrayType(BUDT, containsNull = false), nullable = true)))
  override def userClass: Class[A] = classOf[A]
  override def serialize(obj: Any): Any = obj match {
    case A(list) =>
      val row = new GenericMutableRow(1)
      row.update(0, new GenericArrayData(list.map(_.asInstanceOf[Any]).toArray))
      row
  }

  override def deserialize(datum: Any): A = {
    datum match {
      case row: InternalRow => new A(row.getArray(0).toArray(BUDT).toSeq)
    }
  }
}

object AUDT extends AUDT

@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[BUDT])
case class B(num:Int)

class BUDT extends UserDefinedType[B] {
  override def sqlType: DataType = StructType(Seq(StructField("num", IntegerType, nullable = false)))
  override def userClass: Class[B] = classOf[B]
  override def serialize(obj: Any): Any = obj match {
    case B(num) =>
      val row = new GenericMutableRow(1)
      row.setInt(0, num)
      row
  }

  override def deserialize(datum: Any): B = {
    datum match {
      case row: InternalRow => new B(row.getInt(0))
    }
  }
}

object BUDT extends BUDT

object TestNested {
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val col = Seq(new A(Seq(new B(1), new B(2))),
                  new A(Seq(new B(3), new B(4))))

    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("TestSpark"))
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val df = sc.parallelize(1 to 2 zip col).toDF()
    df.show()

    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(...)
  }
}
```

This results in the following error:

> 15/09/16 16:44:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0
>   (TID 1) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nested type should be
>   repeated: required group array { required int32 num; } at
>   org.apache.parquet.schema.ConversionPatterns.listWrapper(ConversionPatterns.java:42)
>   at
>   org.apache.parquet.schema.ConversionPatterns.listType(ConversionPatterns.java:97)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:460)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:318)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:522)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:521)
>   at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
>   at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:521)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:318)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:526)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:318)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:311)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:311)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:92) at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.map(StructType.scala:92) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convert(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:311)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$.convertFromAttributes(ParquetTypesConverter.scala:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.RowWriteSupport.init(ParquetTableSupport.scala:55)
>   at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:288)
>   at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:272)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:234)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 15/09/16 16:44:39 WARN
>   TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost):

If a save a dataframe with B instead of A no problem exists since B as no nested custom class. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to make four changes to your code to make it work (tested in Spark 1.6.0 on Linux) and I think I can *mostly* explain why they're needed. I do find myself wondering, however, whether there's a simpler solution. All the changes are in `AUDT`, as follows:

1. When defining `sqlType`, make it depend on `BUDT.sqlType`, rather than just `BUDT`.
2. In `serialize()`, call `BUDT.serialize()` on each list element.
3. In `deserialize()`:

   - call `toArray(BUDT.sqlType)` instead of `toArray(BUDT)`
   - call `BUDT.deserialize()` on every element

Here's the resulting code:

```scala
class AUDT extends UserDefinedType[A] {
  override def sqlType: DataType =
    StructType(
      Seq(StructField("list",
                      ArrayType(BUDT.sqlType, containsNull = false),
                      nullable = true)))

  override def userClass: Class[A] = classOf[A]

  override def serialize(obj: Any): Any = 
    obj match {
      case A(list) =>
        val row = new GenericMutableRow(1)
        val elements =
          list.map(_.asInstanceOf[Any])
              .map(e => BUDT.serialize(e))
              .toArray
        row.update(0, new GenericArrayData(elements))
        row
    }

  override def deserialize(datum: Any): A = {
    datum match {
      case row: InternalRow => 
        val first = row.getArray(0)
        val bs:Array[InternalRow] = first.toArray(BUDT.sqlType)
        val bseq = bs.toSeq.map(e => BUDT.deserialize(e))
        val a = new A(bseq)
        a
    }
  }

}
```

All four changes have the same character: the relationship between handling of `A`s and handling of `B`s is now very explicit: for schema typing, for serialization and for de-serialization. The original code seems to be based on the assumption that Spark SQL will "just figure it out", which might be reasonable, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: That worked. I'm using "complex" objects as columns in a DataFrame and in Spark 1.6.0 it stopped working. This did the trick, so the lesson I learned is just make everything regarding serialization/de-serialization very explicit. Cheers!